# How to record League of Legends with OBS?

Tags: league-of-legends, obs

I know how to record with OBS, but when I try to record my League of Legends games, the video just turns black with only the mouse icon seen.

Comment: If you have a Nvidia video card, you can use [Shadowplay](http://www.geforce.com/geforce-experience/shadowplay). I haven't personally tried it yet but those that did were all very impress on how easy it was to use and the video quality was good.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Recording or streaming League of Legends is somewhat tricky. The game uses 2 different windows: one for the client and one for the game.

The easiest way to stream/record League of Legends is by running the game in (borderless) windowed mode.

Now depending on whether you want to just record the game or the game and the client you might want to use the [**OBS Scene Switcher Plugin**](https://obsproject.com/forum/threads/simple-scene-switcher.12616/). This plugin allows you to automatically switch to the right scene when changing your focus. However If you're only interested in recording the game it's not necessary.

For the game recording itself you just have to add a scene with **window capture**. The window you have to select in order to stream or record the game is called **League of Legends (TM) Client**. If you have done this you should be able to record your games.

I would also recommend saving these settings in your scene collection since it's really annoying to configure these settings all over again if you have to restart the program.

Answer (score 0):

Which kind of source are you using to record? This sounds like you're trying to use the window recorder while the game is running in fullscreen mode. Have you tried using the Game Recording instead? As an alternative, switch LoL to windowed/borderless fullscreen.